# two way binding in d3js is causing a issue.how to avoid it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, d3.js

I am using this code and data in variable is also changing how to avoid changes done in variable. For each loop I am using is cause. Or need to do any changes.

```
var str='',
b=gv_chartDataModel,a=[]; 

if(selkeyword!=="IF"){
  a=gv_contextData; 
}else{ 
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) { 
        var source = b.children[j]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < source.children.length; i++) { 
            a.push(source.children[i]) 
        }
    } 
} 

var val = this.value; 
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){ 
    var temp_array=[];
    a[i].children.forEach(function(d){ 
        if(d.description.indexOf(val) !==-1){ 
            temp_array.push(d); 
        }else{ 
            a[i].children.push(d);
        } 
    });

    a[i].children=temp_array; 
}
```

Comment: var str='',b=gv_chartDataModel,a=[];  if(selkeyword!=="IF"){       a=gv_contextData;           }  else{   for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {      var source = b.children[j];   for (var i = 0; i < source.children.length; i++) {     a.push(source.children[i])          }   }              }   var val = this.value; for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                    var temp_array=[]
                     a[i].children.forEach(function(d){  if(d.description.indexOf(val) !==-1){   temp_array.push(d);    }   else{     a[i].children.push(d);      }    })   a[i].children=temp_array;      }.

Comment: Use the "edit" link to add the the code to your question. No one can read code in comments.

Comment: content is large and not allowing changes

Comment: You can edit the question and add the piece of code there